# I have split my PPPoE connection with an Ethernet switch and now I am getting the same speed in both PC simultaneously. why is that?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch, pppoe

Not that I am complaining or anything, its just that I am overwhelmed! I have a PC and a laptop and a Netgear 5 port Fast Ethernet Switch. I connected both of my computers to the switch and started seperate downloads from them and voila! I am getting the exact speed that I pay for, for each PC and simultaneously. But why? can someone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Can you give us some numbers?  i.e. your line speed, and the observed download rates on each machine?

Comment: Do you have configured PPPoE client on both computers? Does your ISP allow you to do so? If not, how have you configured sharing connection?

Answer (score 0):

The only likely explanation of this behavior is that the bottleneck is actually from the downloads source.

Your ISP will only allow up to a certain speed (this may be more than you think) however if you was to find a source that would 'max' out your ISP speed limit then you would definitely see the speed hit on the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do the two devices make seperate PPPoE connections?

If so then I would guess that your ISP has set a speed limit on each PPPoE connection and didn't put in place any restrictions to stop a customer making multiple PPPoE connections at once or to limit the aggregate bandwidth of multiple connections from the same customer.